# Probabilty with Combinations concept check

Tags: probability, combinations, conditional-probability

When we calculate the probability of a random selection of $3$ students being all boys, from a group of $6$ boys and $4$ girls, then we can just multiply $\mathbb P(\text{1st being boy}) \times \mathbb P(\text{2nd being boy}) \times \mathbb P(\text{3rd being boy})$ i.e. $\frac 6 {10} \times \frac 5 9 \times \frac 4 8 $.

But when we need the probability of two coin flips being TAILS in $5$ flips of a fair coin, we need to multiply the $\mathbb P(T)\times\mathbb P(T)\times\mathbb P(H)\times\mathbb P(H)\times\mathbb P(H)\times{5\choose 2}$.

Why do we need to multiply the probabilities by the **number of combinations** in the coin flips problem but not in the first?

Comment: The first question : you pick three people, so first ,second and third picks have to be boys. Second question : two coin flips being tails out of five : but *which* two coin flips? First and third? Second and fourth? First and last? Indeed, any of them, so you accommodate all of them with the $5C2$. Note that , actually you are multiplying by "$3C0 = 1$" in the first one, because you are fitting in $0$ girls into $3$ slots, which can be done in only one way. But when you fit $2$ tails in five slots, the number $5C2 \neq 1$ becomes significant.

Comment: Conceptually, we can also think of it as multiplying by "3C3 = 1" in the first problem i.e. how many ways to fit 3 boys in 3 slots?

Comment: C'est bien,that too would work, since choosing girls for certain slots also amounts to choosing boys for the remaining slots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is only one way to get three boys.  If you were calculating the probability of getting two boys and one girl, you could do $\frac 6{10} \cdot \frac 59 \frac 48$, which chooses two boys first, then one girl, then multiply by $3$ because there are three orders you can choose the three children.